# Unknown table engine 'InnoDB problem

Tags: mysql, innodb

I installed a MySQL Server 5.1 on my machine (Windows Server 2008) and I chose MyISAM as the default DB storage engine. I created one empty DB on it just for testing. Later I reconfigured it using the MySQL Server Instance Config Wizard to use InnoDB as default storage engine. Now when I made the changes and tried to restart the MySQL service, it keeps crashing. It just doesn't start. How can I access the error log to see whats the problem?

It only starts if I run the Server Config wizard again and choose the MyISAM engine as default. Once it starts and when I do "SHOW ENGINES", it does show me InnoDB in a row but when I do "SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS", it gives me Unknown table engine'innodb' error. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: When you execute `SHOW ENGINES`, what is the value of the `Support` column for `InnoDB`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have the Innodb disabled. Try this and restart

Shut down MySQL
Open my.ini in MySQL program folder.
In my.ini replace 
 skip-innodb
with:
 # skip-innodb
Save and restart Mysql